# How to remove newline and instead add comma?

Tags: c, string

In this code, I want to remove the newline. It means whenever I print this variable, it should give me a string without a newline but instead, the comma should replace it. I can directly add a comma when declaring but I want a separate result.

**Expecting output**

```
This,is,a,simple,sentence
```

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char str[] = "This\nis\na\nsimple\nsentence";
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: whats output you expecting?

Comment: @user3121023 how?

Comment: Or just a plain for loop. If you don't know how to do basic stuff like this, you'll need to study the basics in a C book. An answer teaching someone how to use for loops, arrays and strings would be way too long.

Comment: Which part of the `strchr` manpage causes problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a one-line `while` loop using the [`strchr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) function from the standard library to replace each newline character with a comma:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "This\nis\na\nsimple\nsentence";
    char* np;
    while ((np = strchr(str, '\n')) != NULL) *np = ',';
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

A more efficient way of searching through the string is to use the last-found position (while there is one) as the starting-point for the search in the next loop:

```c
int main()
{
    char str[] = "This\nis\na\nsimple\nsentence";
    char* np = str;
    while ((np = strchr(np, '\n')) != NULL) *np = ',';
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a https://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter solution.  Inefficient.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Inefficient - yes! Simple, though, and a reasonable introduction to the `strchr` function?

Comment: Better to start searching from the previous value of `np`. That will make it linear instead of quadratic time.

Comment: @interjay - I was just about to add such code ... give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

A simple for loop will do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(str); i++)
    if (str[i] == '\n')
        str[i] = ',';
```

This modifies the original string, rather than creating a new one.